# Download video in Python using requests module results in black video

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

This is the URL I tried to download: https://www.instagram.com/p/B-jEqo9Bgk9/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link

This is a minimal reproducible example:

```py
import os
import requests


def main():
    filename = 'test.mp4'
    r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/B-jEqo9Bgk9/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link', stream=True)
    with open(os.path.join('.', filename), 'wb') as f:
        print('Dumping "{0}"...'.format(filename))
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            print(chunk)
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
                f.flush()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code runs fine but the video does not play. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I made an edit to improve the question and edited the code to be a [mre] so others can run and test your code too. This will make it easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running perfectly fine, but you did not provide the correct link for the video. The link you used is for the Instagram web page, not the video. So you should not save the content as 'test.mp4', but rather as 'test.html'. If you open the file in a text editor (for example Notepad++), you will see that it contains the HTML code of the web page.

You'll need to parse the HTML to acquire the actual video URL, and then you can use the same code to download the video using that URL.

Currently, the line that starts with `meta property="og:video" content=` contains the actual video URL, but that may change in the future.

(*Note that copyright may apply for videos on Instagram. I assume you have the rights to download and save this video.*)